# What are some resources for non-tea-leaf cryptocurrency trading strategies?

Tags: trading, investing

I've heard of some bizarre cryptocurrency trading strategies that basically amount to reading tea leaves:

- patterns of five, referencing that we have 5 senses, 5 fingers on each hand, and thus one can assume 5 patterns in a day for trading, lol
- fibonacci analysis

Can you point me in the direction of some resources for somewhat scientific trading strategies that work to reduce trading risk? For instance, here are two that I've heard:

- [Market Cap Distribution Analysis](https://t.co/aXk6A8S2px)
- Cross-Exchange Arbitrage. Buy cheaper on one exchange, sell higher on another exchange, pocket the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trading on Poloniex for about 8 months now and Ill tell you what I've learned about trading crypto-currency:

There really is no method to the madness. You can try to follow trends, you can try to read the charts and watch markers and signals for whatever they are supposed to signal. But honestly, it just kinda does what it does.

I've found that trying to trade from exchange to exchange trying to take advantage of small price difference is tough because of how long it can take for different coins transactions to be confirmed. It's easy to miss a quick swing in price while waiting for funds to be confirmed.

Watching for news articles or coverage of a specific coin and then trying to trade on the news is also tough. Again because you can't​ be everywhere at once. The news might not inspire US investors but it might inspire Asia or European investors and they don't wake up until you go to bed. So it's easy to miss out on an afternoon rally in Asia when it's 3am where you live.

Here is what I have found to be helpful. The crypto currency market is a rollercoaster. It swings up and it swings down. And it does it very quickly and often. So here's what I do, base your buy and sell decisions on the average price over a period of time. I like to use two week intervals. Take the daily high for the two weeks and get an average price. Take the  daily low for the two weeks and get an average. Place a buy at about 5 to 10 percent above the average low and place a sell about 10 to 20 percent above the  average high. Then wait. Wait for it to reach the high you set and sell. Then wait for it to come back down (because it always does) and buy again.

If you do that over and over again over time you'll make a decent profit. You just have to be willing to wait a few weeks sometimes for it to reach the high your looking for.

Comment: Again, I'm a total noob, but would you consider this as "swing trading"?

Comment: I don't know what that is, but that sounds like what im doing.

Comment: Another thing is be careful which coins you choose to trade. You don't want to unknowingly get caught in a pump and dump. Also I don't trade anything that doesn't have a USDT trading pair. I feel like these coins are more "legit" than others since they have a real USD trading value (as opposed to coins that only have a BTC trading value).